# In Intellij how do you Reformat Multiple Files of a particular type

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project with 20+ modules in Intellij.  Each module contains a mixture of file types including java, groovy, jsp, etc.  In the past we've found found some Intellij bugs in which running Reformat and Optimize Import can actually insert bugs in Groovy and JSP files.  So I'd like to be able to execute a single Reformat/Optimize operation across all my modules which will only process the java files.  I hoped that the **Scopes** functionality would allow me to do this, but it doesn't appear to be working as I'd expect.  The pattern that I'm using for the Custom Scope is:

```
file[*]:**/*/*.java
```

In the **Edit Scopes** dialog when I drill down to the file level, the Java files are in fact the only ones that appear, so the Scope appears to be working.

Then in the main editor window, I expand the **Project** tool window and select my new **Scope** in the drop down at the top of the Tool window.  This displays all of my modules in the Tool Window.  I then highlight all of the modules, right click and select **Reformat Code**.  However, this still reformats all file types (groovy, jsp, java, etc.).

Whether or not **Scopes** is the answer, does anyone know how to pull this off?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with scopes and there is an open feature request to support it, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59850).

Right now you can select multiple files and perform reformat in the selected files, I'm afraid it's the only way.